# Automatic Update from Excel to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

I need to load the data from excel to a table in SQL Server 2008 and automate the updates.ie., If there is a new record or an update to the existing record in the source excel it should automatically update the SQL Server Table.

Is it possible, if yes how?

Any ideas or suggestions would be helpful.

I Use: Excel 2013 - MS SQL

Comment: You need to write a Office Add-In to do this, as you cannot read an Excel file that is already open.

Comment: You a unique key (sometimes known as a primary key) to decide whether a row has changed. Does your table have a unique key? If so it's pretty straightforward to write some VBA to write the data back to the database. You need to consider your security though - how do you want to connect? There is a lot of sample code everywhere. Have you written VBA before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created an Excel Add-In that will insert new rows in Excel into the SQL Server table and also update changes in existing rows in Excel into the SQL Server Table.

It is a commerial prodcut, but if it is a time limited job, you can use the full functional trial for free (and if you need, just send me an email and I'll extended the trial for you).

You can download the Excel AddIn from http://sqlspreads.com/download-sql-spreads/

Answer (score 0):

I would check if something has changed on your excel worksheet and if so insert it into your database table. You can handle all of these steps using VBA.

Let me know if you need further information how to handle database connections via VBA.

Comment: Okey no problem for using VBA if it could help in achieving the required process, if you have a piece of code to adjust in my DB, i will be grateful